# Solving differential equation $\frac{\sqrt{x}dx+\sqrt{y}dy}{\sqrt{x}dx-\sqrt{y}dy}=\sqrt{\frac{y^3}{x^3}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the following diffrential equation.
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}dx+\sqrt{y}dy}{\sqrt{x}dx-\sqrt{y}dy}=\sqrt{\frac{y^3}{x^3}}$$

My try:

First I applied C and D to get (componendo and dividendo)
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}dx}{\sqrt{y}dy}=\frac{y^{3/2}+x^{3/2}}{y^{3/2}-x^{3/2}}$$
On simplifying
$$\sqrt{xy}(ydx-xdy)=x^2dx+y^2dy$$

Now by seeing $(ydx-xdy)$ I got hint of forming $d(\frac{x}{y})$ but for it I need to divide by $y^2$ which will disturb other terms. I am stuck at this step. Please provide some hint to proceed. Thanks

Comment: What is "C and D"? Btw, typo in title (e missing)

Comment: Letting $x=u^{2/3},y=v^{2/3},$ the equation becomes $\frac{du}{dv}=\frac{v+u}{v-u}.$

Comment: Nice question.
Im not from UK or US (so?) , I do not know what " C and D " means. And Apparantly I am not alone. Please clarify.

Comment: @AnneBauval C and D means componendo and dividendo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your last ine:
$$\sqrt{xy}(ydx-xdy)=x^2dx+y^2dy$$
$$y^2\sqrt{xy}d\left(\dfrac xy\right)=\dfrac 13d(x^3+y^3)$$
$$y^3\sqrt{\dfrac xy}d\left(\dfrac xy\right)=\dfrac 13d(x^3+y^3)$$
Note that:
$$y^3+x^3=y^3 \left(1+\dfrac {x^3}{y^3}\right)$$
Deduce that:
$$\implies y^3=\dfrac {x^3+y^3}{ \left(1+\dfrac {x^3}{y^3}\right)}$$
Then the DE becomes separable:
$$\dfrac {{2v^2}}{1+v^6}dv=\dfrac {du}{3u}$$
Where $u=x^3+y^3$ and $v= \sqrt {\dfrac xy}$.
$$\dfrac {{dv^3}}{1+v^6}=\dfrac {du}{2u}$$
$$2\arctan (v^3)=\ln u +C$$

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea. Here's a slightly different approach:

**1.** Let's start with substitutions to remove radicals:
$$
\begin{cases}
u = \sqrt{x}  \\
v = \sqrt{y}
\end{cases}
$$
So $x = u^2$ and $\mathrm{d}x = 2u\,\mathrm{d}u$, and similarly,
$y = v^2$ and $\mathrm{d}y = 2v\,\mathrm{d}v$.
Now, the differential equation reads
$$
\frac{2u^2\,\mathrm{d}u + 2v^2\,\mathrm{d}v}{2u^2\,\mathrm{d}u - 2v^2\,\mathrm{d}v} 
= \frac{v^3}{u^3},
$$
or by clearing denominators,
$$
2u^5\,\mathrm{d}u + 2u^3v^2\,\mathrm{d}v = 2u^2v^3\,\mathrm{d}u - 2v^5\,\mathrm{d}v.
$$
Separating differentials gives
$$
(v^5 + u^3v^2)\,\mathrm{d}v = (u^2v^3 - u^5)\,\mathrm{d}u
$$
or
$$
v^2(v^3 + u^3)\,\mathrm{d}v = u^2(v^3 - u^3)\,\mathrm{d}u. 
$$

**2.** Since this equation is homogeneous, it makes sense to put $w = \dfrac{v}{u}$ or $v = wu$, which implies that
$$
\mathrm{d}v = u\,\mathrm{d}w + w\,\mathrm{d}u,
$$
so
$$
w^2u^2(w^3u^3 + u^3)\,(u\,\mathrm{d}w + w\,\mathrm{d}u) 
= u^2(w^3u^3 - u^3)\,\mathrm{d}u. 
$$
Dividing by $u^5$ yields
$$
w^2(w^3 + 1)\,(u\,\mathrm{d}w + w\,\mathrm{d}u) 
= (w^3 - 1)\,\mathrm{d}u, 
$$
so
$$
uw^2(1 + w^3)\,\mathrm{d}w = -(1 + w^6)\,\mathrm{d}u, 
$$
and finally
$$
\frac{w^2 + w^5}{1 + w^6}\,\mathrm{d}w = -\frac{1}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u.  
$$

**3.** Now that the variables are separated, we can integrate (using substitutions on the left-hand side):
\begin{align} 
\int \frac{w^2 + w^5}{1 + w^6}\,\mathrm{d}w 
&= \int \frac{w^2}{1 + w^6}\,\mathrm{d}w 
+ \int \frac{w^5}{1 + w^6}\,\mathrm{d}w \\ 
&= \frac13 \int \frac{3w^2}{1 + (w^3)^2}\,\mathrm{d}w 
+ \frac16 \int \frac{6w^5}{1 + w^6}\,\mathrm{d}w \\ 
&= \frac13 \arctan(w^3) + \frac16 \ln(1 + w^6) 
\end{align}

Hence, we have the solution equation
$$
2 \arctan(w^3) + \ln(1 + w^6) + \ln u = 0, 
$$

**4.** Back substitute and simplify.
$$
2 \arctan \frac{v^3}{u^3} 
+ \ln\biggl(1 + \frac{v^6}{u^6}\biggr) 
+ \ln u = 0, 
$$
Finally,
$$
2 \arctan \sqrt{\frac{y^3}{x^3}} 
+ \ln\biggl(1 + \frac{y^3}{x^3}\biggr) 
+ \ln \sqrt{x} = 0, 
$$
or by using logarithm properties
$$
4 \arctan \sqrt{\frac{y^3}{x^3}} 
+ 2\ln(x^3 + y^3) 
- 5\ln x = 0.
$$